# Optaplanner error when upgrading from 8.4.0 to 8.5.0

Tags: java, drools, quarkus, optaplanner

Till now I used Optaplanner version `8.4.0.Final` in my program. I wanted to upgrade to `8.5.0.Final` and the program is not working anymore. If I downgrade it to `8.4.0.Final` it again works just fine. Is there anything I should take care of before the upgrade? I'm using Quarkus and `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev` works fine - I get this message:

```
2021-04-22 12:00:27,418 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) my-program 1.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.11.4.Final) started in 11.229s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
```

After sending the same request that was working on `8.4.0.Final`, I get this error message:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting org.optaplanner.core.api.score.ScoreManager<org.acme.optaplanner.domain.TaskRouteAssigning, org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScore> org.acme.optaplanner.rest.UrnikOskrbeResource.scoreManager
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:381)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:138)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:231)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting org.optaplanner.core.api.score.ScoreManager<org.acme.optaplanner.domain.TaskRouteAssigning, org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScore> org.acme.optaplanner.rest.UrnikOskrbeResource.scoreManager
        at org.acme.optaplanner.rest.UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.create(UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.zig:179)
        at org.acme.optaplanner.rest.UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.create(UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.zig:245)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.access$000(AbstractSharedContext.java:14)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at org.acme.optaplanner.rest.UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.get(UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.zig:277)
        at org.acme.optaplanner.rest.UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.get(UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.zig:293)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:435)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:448)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$1.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:271)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$1.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:268)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.BeanContainerImpl$1.create(BeanContainerImpl.java:35)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.runtime.QuarkusConstructorInjector.construct(QuarkusConstructorInjector.java:54)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:71)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:386)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:68)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:///C:/Users/ar1826/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core-deployment/1.11.4.Final/quarkus-core-deployment-1.11.4.Final.jar
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.FSInfo.getJarClassPath(FSInfo.java:112)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.CacheFSInfo.getJarClassPath(CacheFSInfo.java:93)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addJarClassPath(Locations.java:423)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addFile(Locations.java:413)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addFiles(Locations.java:345)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addFiles(Locations.java:333)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addFiles(Locations.java:339)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$ClassPathLocationHandler.computePath(Locations.java:779)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SimpleLocationHandler.setPaths(Locations.java:721)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.setLocation(Locations.java:2098)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.setLocation(JavacFileManager.java:927)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.jdknative.NativeJavaCompiler.compile(NativeJavaCompiler.java:80)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:41)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad(KieMemoryCompiler.java:130)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad(KieMemoryCompiler.java:102)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compile(KieMemoryCompiler.java:53)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compile(KieMemoryCompiler.java:39)
        at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.inMemoryUpdate(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:66)
        at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.run(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:52)
        at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.generateAndSetInMemoryANC(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:99)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.DroolsConstraintSessionFactory.buildKieBaseFromModel(DroolsConstraintSessionFactory.java:91)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.DroolsConstraintSessionFactory.<init>(DroolsConstraintSessionFactory.java:70)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.DroolsConstraintFactory.buildSessionFactory(DroolsConstraintFactory.java:100)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.AbstractConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.<init>(AbstractConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:65)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.<init>(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:29)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:220)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.decideMultipleScoreDirectorFactories(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:100)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:68)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:116)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.getScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:73)
        at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.ScoreManager.create(ScoreManager.java:59)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider.scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore(OptaPlannerBeanProvider.java:128)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore_27709e07743a8ec22f255af32ffa867a488769b9_Bean.create(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore_27709e07743a8ec22f255af32ffa867a488769b9_Bean.zig:208)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore_27709e07743a8ec22f255af32ffa867a488769b9_Bean.create(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore_27709e07743a8ec22f255af32ffa867a488769b9_Bean.zig:232)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.access$000(AbstractSharedContext.java:14)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore_27709e07743a8ec22f255af32ffa867a488769b9_Bean.get(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore_27709e07743a8ec22f255af32ffa867a488769b9_Bean.zig:264)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore_27709e07743a8ec22f255af32ffa867a488769b9_Bean.get(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_scoreManager_workaroundHardMediumSoftScore_27709e07743a8ec22f255af32ffa867a488769b9_Bean.zig:280)
        at org.acme.optaplanner.rest.UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.create(UrnikOskrbeResource_Bean.zig:162)
        ... 38 more
```

I'm using Windows if that changes some things. I have also a problem with running the quickstarts - the listening on localhost starts but the solving causes an error. I tried deleting and re-loading things in `quarkus-core-deployment`

Comment: Do you have the same error with optaplanner-quickstarts? Or a different error? Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: This is the first line (can't copy everything as the comments are char limited):
`org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:///C:/Users/ar1826/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core-deployment/1.11.4.Final/quarkus-core-deployment-1.11.4.Final.jar`
It's like one of the errors in my own case. 

I'm using JDK 11.

Comment: I just tried `optaplanner-quickstarts` on Windows 10, by running `cd quarkus-school-timetabling; mvn quarkus:dev` and it worked fine on my machine, using JDK 11. I am really interested in what's going on here. Can you please try "java --version"?

Comment: `java --version` returns: openjdk 11 2018-09-25, OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28), OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode). I git cloned the `optaplanner-quickstarts` and run it the same way as you did and I got the same error as in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression in Drools, under investigation:
https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232677-drools/topic/Windows

Update:
[This is the fix](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/pull/3601) (which will land in 8.7 or 8.8).

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make it work or just proceed with 8.4.0 and hoping for the best in 8.6.0?

Comment: There's a PR to fix it, so 8.7 will have the fix if it's not cut yet. Thanks again for reporting :)

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error aswell. Is there a solution to this?

I am using Windows 10, Optaplanner 8.8.0 Final, OpenJDK 11

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: .../2.0.2.Final/quarkus-core-deployment-2.0.2.Final.jar
 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.FSInfo.getJarClassPath(FSInfo.java:112)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.CacheFSInfo.getJarClassPath(CacheFSInfo.java:93)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addJarClassPath(Locations.java:423)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addFile(Locations.java:413)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addFiles(Locations.java:345)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addFiles(Locations.java:333)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SearchPath.addFiles(Locations.java:339)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$ClassPathLocationHandler.computePath(Locations.java:779)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$SimpleLocationHandler.setPaths(Locations.java:721)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.setLocation(Locations.java:2098)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.setLocation(JavacFileManager.java:927)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.jdknative.NativeJavaCompiler.compile(NativeJavaCompiler.java:80)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:41)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad(KieMemoryCompiler.java:130)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad(KieMemoryCompiler.java:102)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compile(KieMemoryCompiler.java:53)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compile(KieMemoryCompiler.java:39)
        at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.inMemoryUpdate(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:66)
        at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.run(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:52)
        at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.generateAndSetInMemoryANC(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:99)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.DroolsConstraintSessionFactory.buildKieBaseFromModel(DroolsConstraintSessionFactory.java:85)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.DroolsConstraintSessionFactory.buildSession(DroolsConstraintSessionFactory.java:126)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.newConstraintStreamingSession(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:50)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.resetConstraintStreamingSession(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.java:75)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.java:67)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.SolverScope.setWorkingSolutionFromBestSolution(SolverScope.java:215)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:80)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:200)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:174)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverJob.call(DefaultSolverJob.java:101)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```